# Veeery old review answer

Tags: bug, review

The answer under review was posted about 5 years ago. Why is it in the queue **now**?

https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/188424 (available to mods and 10k+ users)

Comment: That's a really good question. It wasn't an audit.

Comment: I had a similar review just now http://serverfault.com/review/low-quality-posts/189268 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer at Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222413/204631) posits that this is OK:

> This is, while unusual, an expected result of the system.
>
> The way the late answers queue works is by checking two things.
>
> - Was the answer posted at least 30 days after the question was asked?
> - Was the answer posted by a user who has 10 or less reputation (disregarding suspension)
>
> If both of these are true, it is entered into the review queue until it eventually gets reviewed. In most cases, this will catch things as they come in and so you will only see new posts, so we don't spend any resources checking time.
>
> However, on rare occasion, someone will actually drop below 10 reputation, while having some past answer that does qualify. That's what happened in your example - the user received a dunk in reputation from 15 down to 5 on December 21st, 2013, and so this ancient post of theirs that has not previously been reviewed, is now put into review that same day.

I am not really sure this is the case here, though. Would be nice to have an official confirmation either way.

Comment: That seems to be what happened here. The user who posted the answer being reviewed did drop to 1 reputation just before the review task was generated.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - thanks for the investigation.